# Open second form from third form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms. The second is for displaying help, the third is a modal dialog.

In Form1 I have:

```
Form2 HelpForm = new Form2();
Form3 EditForm = new Form3();
```

and a Help menu that just does:

```
HelpForm.Show();
```

I would like to show HelpForm also from a control in Form3. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just instantiate a `HelpForm` in the event handler in `Form3`?

Answer (score 1):

the help is kind of global and (if your application grows) it should be accessible anywhere. So maybe a (kind of) Singleton for your Help could help!

```
class Help
{
   private static Form helpForm = null;
   static void ShowHelp {
     if (helpForm == null)
        helpForm = generateHelpForm(); //TODO implement

     helpForm.Show();
 }
```

access it from anywhere...

```
// somewhere in formx
Help.ShowHelp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass HelpForm object in the constructor of EditForm and assign the same in private variable. Invoke show when needed using the variable.

```
Form2 HelpForm = new Form2();
Form3 EditForm = new Form3(HelpForm);
 .....
EditForm.ShowHelp();
```

With in Form3:

```
 Class Form3
 {
    private Form2 helpForm = null;

     public Form3(Form2 HelpForm)
      {
          helpForm = HelpForm;
       }

       public void ShowHelp()
      {
          helpForm.Show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: In fact, I have realized that opening EditForm as modal was not adequate. I need to consult help while editing, and it was impossible to have HelpForm under EditForm and above Form1. I'm opening it as non-modal and just disabling some commands in Form1 while it's open, so Help menu is always available.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use `Application.OpenForms`

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

if (fc.OfType<Form3>().Any())
{
   fc.OfType<Form3>().First().Show();
}
```